# Code not running when using ".remove()" function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing this jquery code :

```
$('form').after('<p id="suc"></p>');
$('#suc').html('success !');
$('#suc').show(700);
setTimeout(function(){$('#suc').hide('slow')},2500);
$('#suc').remove();
```

When i remove `$('#suc').remove();` like this :

```
$('form').after('<p id="suc"></p>');
$('#suc').html('success !');
$('#suc').show(700);
setTimeout(function(){$('#suc').hide('slow')},2500);
```

The code run succefuly, but when i put it, it dosen't run !!

What the problem with that ?
it's illegal to but `$('#suc').remove();` here ?

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` call doesn't wait for the callback to run before the code continues, so you will be removing the element immediately. When the code in the callback tries to hide the element, it's not there.

Remove the element in the `complete` callback of the [`hide` method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#suc').hide('slow', function(){
    $('#suc').remove();
  });
},2500);
```

Comment: thank you in advance,it's now running..but i need more explaination : what happend is that the whole code not running not only that last tow sentences ! so what the reason of that ?

Comment: @walid: The element will be removed even before the `show` animation runs.

Comment: but why !!? is it running asynchronously ?

Comment: @walid: Yes, all animations are asynchronous. There are no updates in the browser while your function is running, so animations have to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) you're also safe to use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), so:

```
$('#suc').show(700).delay(2500).hide('slow', function () {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

will suffice.

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/isediz/2/

---

Also, as a bit of clarification, regarding:

> The code run succefuly, but when i put it, it dosen't run !!

Actually the code runs (in a sense), the problem is that your `remove` will not wait for the two asynchrones events (`setTimeout` and `.hide('slow')`). So it will get executed way before those two are done doing what they should do.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the element `setTimout` callback which you have already removed with the statement just after setTimout. The call back of `setTimeout` will execute after the statement removing element with id `#suc` by the next statement of setTimeout. *Remove `#suc` in hide callback so that it is not accessed by script after removal*.

```
$('form').after('<p id="suc"></p>');
$('#suc').html('success !');
$('#suc').show(700);
setTimeout(function(){
      $('#suc').hide('slow', 
           function(){$(this).remove();
      }); 
},2500);
```

Comment: I dont think so, setInterval is for 25 seconds here.

Comment: It's `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `remove()` inside of the `setTimeout` and in the callback for the `hide()` function:

```
$('form').after('<p id="suc"></p>');
$('#suc').html('success !');
$('#suc').show(700);

setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#suc').hide('slow', function() { $(this).remove(); })
}, 2500);
```